# How to do query and assignment with Linq in one statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I am gathering the product table from corporate to see it they have adjusted any prices on their end. So after preloading the PriceCheckList List with the differences I want to find the row in my dbmodel where my name (product) matches theirs and then update MyPrice from Their Price in one go. Doesn't error, just doesn't seem to be updating my Items table. Am I doing it right?

```
    DbModels db = new DbModels();
    foreach (var row in PriceCheckList)
    {
        db.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.MyName == row.TheirName).MyPrice = row.TheirPrice;
  
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
```

TIA

Comment: Not answering your question at all, just a note: using ````FirstOrDefault```` means you expect a case when no items match the expression given and in this case the method will return ````null````. But depite this fact you are trying to set the ````MyPrice```` property of it risking a ````NullReferenceException```` each time the expressions matches no items.

Comment: Your construct is unusual, but I see no reason it shouldn't work. Have you tried any debugging? (LINQ is for querying, it would perhaps be more idiomatic to have `var matchingItem = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(...); if (matchingItem != null) matchingItem.MyPrice = row.TheirPrice;`

Comment: I would fetch whole collection according to filter once (single IO operation), then do update within foreach. Though, cache might be used. But anyway.

Comment: I just gave up at used good old SQL statements. Had to get er done.